# Android canvas width and height volatility

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

I'm creating an Android application which does quite a lot of processing inside the `onDraw(Canvas canvas)` method of my `View` class.  **The application forces portrait mode**.

My question is, how safe is it to assume that the height and width of the canvas isn't going to change between calls to the paint method?  The reason I ask is that I then use these values to construct quite a few objects that I use during the onDraw method.  If I assume that height and width won't change then I can cache the 30 or so Objects that are created when the `onDraw` method is first called.

I've done quite a lot of Swing programming and this is definitely something you wouldn't do in Swing, however it seems to me that the height and width of someone's phone is unlikely to change.

Is this a correct assumption?  I've tried it and it works perfectly, however I'm concerned that there might be a gotcha that I haven't appreciated.

Thanks for any guidance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on the things that can happen to your `View`. Which basically translates to: it depends on your `layout` and on the things you're planning to do with your `View`.

So... you can safely assume the size of your `canvas` won't change as long as you can make sure the size of your `View` won't change. If nothing can force your `View` to resize, your `canvas'` size will stay the same.

The easiest method to overcome this issue is to move all the object allocations (which shouldn't sit inside the `onDraw` method anyways) to the `onSizeChanged` method of your `View` (or to `onLayout`). This way, every time your `View's` size is changed (due to something), your objects can be reinitialized or corrected, to work correctly with your `drawing` process.

Comment: `onSizeChanged` method definitely sounds like the safest way to go - thanks!